# Determine whether or not a mongoengine document matches a raw pymongo query in code

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

Let's say I have a list of pymongo queries and a document. the document can be (or not) matched by one or more of the pymongo queries.

e.g.

Here is my document:

```
> db.my_collection.findOne()
{
    "EmbeddedDoc" : {
        "values" : [
            NumberLong(1),
            NumberLong(2)
        ]
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("515407bbc118555eea07fea5"),
    "some_other_value" : "Val",
    "my_id" : NumberLong(42),
}
```

Here is a list of raw pymongo queries (associated with some list of ints):

```
list_of_queries = [
    ({'EmbeddedDoc.values': 2}, [1, 3, 5]) 
    ({'some_other_value': 'H2G2'}, [6, 5])
    ({'some_other_value': 'Val'}, [10, 4])
    ({'my_id': {'$gte': 256}}, [3, 13, 2])
]
```

I want to know the concatenation of the lists of ints, for the queries that match the particular document. In the case above that would be `[1, 3, 5, 10, 4]`

What I've done, so far, was querying the db each time (here a method on `MyCollection` inheriting of mongoengine `Document`):

```
def get_list_of_int(self):
    ints = []
    for query, list_of_ints in list_of_queries:
         if bool(MyCollection.objects(my_id=self.my_id, __raw__=query)):
             ints.extend(list_of_ints)
    return ints
```

However this queries the db each time. Even though this is fast (there is an index on `my_id`), I was wondering if there is a means to determine if the `Document` instance matches a particular query within the code, instead of querying the db (the list of queries can be arbitrarily long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may (or may not) be impossible.

I suspect mongodb search is done in the server, while you want to verify the result in the client. I doubt pymongo bindings can perform same operation client-side.

Consider following decomposition of your problem: `map` -- select documents matching on of queries and `reduce` -- concatenate integers. Fundamentally your options to achieve good performance are:

1. implement map stage in Python (new) and reduce in Python (already)
2. keep map stage in JS and implement reduce stage in JS (new)

map stage for arbitrary JS queries in Python seems like a lot of work.

reduce stage in JS requires that you generate reduce function at runtime, I think, but that should not be too hard.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your anwser. I know that the search is done db-server side, but I was hoping a method in the client side that given a particular document know if a query match or not (in pymongo, mongoengine, or another lib). I was hopping there were some code made for such cases (not found any as for now). moreover I didn't fully understand the second part of your answer could you be more explicit?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem a bit, removed original second part of answer and wrote new option -- server-side map-reduce.

Comment: Everything on JS side is not really an option in my architecture. So It remains the mapping in Python. Indeed it's a lot of work, but I the project we decided to go for that option for a "simple" subset of queries ("simple" in the sense that we are not considering queries with $or (there can be two separate queries), with $regex, Geospatial selector etc). However I'm still curious, whether or not a library that does such a mapping exists?

Comment: Mongodb is written in C++, I hazard a quess that JS evaluation may be performed using some library. Read the source...

Answer (score 0):

I'd venture to say you can't get away with querying the database each time. However adding a caching layer will probably significantly speed things up. I'm presupposing the same queries might be run more than once. If not, caching won't work for you at all.

Here's some sample code (I suggest you use a proper caching engine. The code is just for illustration)

```
cache = {}
def get_list_of_int(self):
ints = []
for query, list_of_ints in list_of_queries:
     if query in cache:
       ints.extend(list_of_ints if cache[query] else [])
     if bool(MyCollection.objects(my_id=self.my_id, __raw__=query)):
         cache[query] = True
         ints.extend(list_of_ints)
     cache[query] = False
return ints
```

Comment: caching won't help me here, the list of queries are not repeating at all. they can overlap (multiple queries are a match for the collection instance), but are definitely not the same. Thanks for your anwser though